# I can't open my local server. I made todo list

Tags: python, django, localhost

**Present states**

I made easy "to do list". I copied and pasted from Japanese website.
These procedures was going well on the way, however when I set up local server, this error occurred

`python manage.py runserver 8080`

---

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
October 14, 2019 - 18:23:49
Django version 2.2.5, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py:88: UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list: <class 'todo.models.Todo'> QuerySet.
  allow_empty_first_page=allow_empty_first_page, **kwargs)
Internal Server Error: /todo/list/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: todo_todo

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 157, in get
    context = self.get_context_data()
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 119, in get_context_data
    paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 69, in paginate_queryset
    page = paginator.page(page_number)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 70, in page
    number = self.validate_number(number)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 48, in validate_number
    if number > self.num_pages:
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 97, in num_pages
    if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\paginator.py", line 91, in count
    return c()
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 392, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 504, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 489, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\kazu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: todo_todo
[14/Oct/2019 18:25:18] "GET /todo/list/ HTTP/1.1" 500 165625
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[14/Oct/2019 18:25:19] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2077
```

---

I don't spot the file which have the errors. so If you know what file has the errors, could you pls tell me? I will post the code in the file.

Comment: Have you run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Answer (score 0):

**`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: todo_todo,`**

This means you have no table called **`todo`** in your database - `db.sqlite3`. You need to make migrations which is standard step in `django` when do changes in `model` and then create tables in your db via commands mentioned above in comments by @YevhenKuzmovych.

1. `python manage.py makemigrations`

then

2. `python manage.py migrate`

> **Make it a habit to always run these two commands when you do any changes to your models.py which contain your model classes**